# Volumes and Areas of parallelepiped, triangle and parallelogram. (Vectors)

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vectors, volume, area

I'm having trouble using the cross product and triple product formula. How do I know which vector to substitute into a,b and c, are these vectors specific to length or some other constraint? And if they are can I scale these vectors if I have worked them out through point subtraction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\overset\rightarrow a,\,\overset\rightarrow b,\, \overset\rightarrow c\,$ are coterminous edges parallelepiped then its volume $=\left|[\overset\rightarrow a\,\, \overset\rightarrow b\,\, \overset\rightarrow c\, ]\right|.$

So does not matter which permutation of $\overset\rightarrow a,\,\overset\rightarrow b,\, \overset\rightarrow c\,$  is taken.